# AngularStrap - load template file in modal template as inner content

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I'm new to Angular-strap and AngularJS. I'm working on a project that is gonna be using both of them.

**Scenario**

My idea is to have multiple Modal template files for Angular-strap (w/ header, w/ header and footer, etc.). In some of these templates I would like to load different HTML file, so the Modal template file can be like a wrapper. The idea is that these different HTML files will have their own controllers and scopes. I would like to use those scopes in Modal template files to display specific data like: title, buttons, text of buttons, etc.

**Problem**

Seems like I'm not able to use both data-template-url and data-content-template (or at least it's not working on my side). I can use one of them, for example, in this case below, only data-template-url is used.

```
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-animation="am-fade-and-slide-top" data-template-url="views/mb-templates/popups/dialog-simple.html" bs-modal="modal" data-content-template="views/mb-templates/dialog-inner-content.html">Custom Modal
                <br />
                <small>(using data-template)</small>
            </button>
```

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to create the scenario that I've described?
2. If it is, how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible if you use templateUrl to return a function, and within the function you make your conditional template selection. The [Angular Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) documentation's section on a "Template-expanding directive" has a good example. Here's a link to the [Template-expanding directive example's Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview). The example's directive code looks like this:

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
      return 'customer-'+attr.type+'.html';
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this one works for the pure Angular. but my idea is to use this approach in AngularStrap. The things there are a bit different :)